# Downloading metadata information from Artifactory

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, artifactory

At the company I work for we are using artifactory like tool of repository management. Now I'm working on a modular project that look like at the following:

[image]

Now, I realized that each day the first time that I try to build my application through the command

> jetty:run

I get the following information:

```
    [INFO] Downloading: http://myRepo/artifactory/repo/it/myCompany/services/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: http://myRepo/artifactory/repo/it/myCompany/services/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://myRepo/artifactory/repo/it/myCompany/parent/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://myRepo/artifactory/repo/it/myCompany/parent/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://myRepo/artifactory/repo/it/myCompany/model/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: http://myRepo/artifactory/repo/it/myCompany/model/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://myRepo/artifactory/repo/it/myCompany/util/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: http://myRepo/artifactory/repo/it/myCompany/util/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http://myRepo/artifactory/repo/it/myCompany/rest/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: http://myRepo/artifactory/repo/it/myCompany/test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
```

I think that these xml files are converted in maven-metadata-repo.xml in the corrisponding folder inside the local repository. For example the file maven-metadata-repo.xml of the model project contains the following info:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <metadata>
      <groupId>myCompany</groupId>
      <artifactId>model</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-20140417.095713-1</version>
      <versioning>
        <snapshot>
          <timestamp>20140417.095713</timestamp>
          <buildNumber>1</buildNumber>
        </snapshot>
        <lastUpdated>20140512073542</lastUpdated>
        <snapshotVersions>
          <snapshotVersion>
            <extension>pom</extension>
            <value>0.0.1-20140417.095713-1</value>
            <updated>20140417095713</updated>
          </snapshotVersion>
          <snapshotVersion>
            <extension>jar</extension>
            <value>0.0.1-20140417.095713-1</value>
            <updated>20140417095713</updated>
          </snapshotVersion>
        </snapshotVersions>
      </versioning>
    </metadata>
```

Now I want to ask you  Why i get the informations of download only the first time (each day) that i run the command jetty:run?
Also I configured the snapshot repository in artifactory in this way[image]

Is this the reason of these continuous download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to the way Maven is checking whether there is an updated SNAPSHOT version of your dependencies (Maven3 is using unique SNAPSHOT versions). Maven downloads the maven-metadata.xml file and checks if it has the latest SNAPSHOT version cached in the local Maven repository or it needs to download a newer one from Artifactory.
The default update policy for SNAPSHOTS is checking once a day ("daily"). You can configure this policy in your [settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-settings/settings.html) file, for example:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>my-server-url</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Possible values for  are: "always", "daily" (default), "interval:XXX" (in minutes) or "never" (only if it doesn't exist locally).